# How to fade in Lottie animation when it loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lottie

I'm using a Lottie animation as the background of my website (made with plain HTML/CSS/JS) controlled by scrolling through ScrollMagic. However, the animation takes about 1 second to load in after the rest of the content appears. It was originally much longer but I was able to reduce the file size and increase compression. I am trying to add a fade in animation to the Lottie when it loads in so it is less jarring than just appearing all of the sudden. The current code I am using to render/load the Lottie is

```
var animData = {
  container: elem,
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  rendererSettings: {
    progressiveLoad: false,
    preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid meet'
  },
  path: './data3.json'
};
bgAnim = lottie.loadAnimation(animData);
```

I tried adding simple css properties like transition to the Lottie animation container, but it did not seem to work. I would appreciate any help/ideas anyone might have.

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to the parent wrapper of the animation and start the fading on a starting frame. Also, if you are using a loop and want fade in and out, you can use `removeClass` during one of the lastest frames or defining `bgAnim.onLoopComplete` function.

CSS:

```
.parent-class {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.fading-in {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
bgAnim.onEnterFrame = ({ currentFrame }) => {
  // not always an integer
  if (currentFrame < 1) {
    jQuery(elem)
      .parent('.parent-class')
      .addClass('fading-in');
  }
}
```